# XSLT: reverse the string by comma

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file:

```
<schools>
    <schcool>
        school1, school2, school3, school4, school5
        </schcool>
    </schools>
```

I want to write XSLT (version 1.0) to change the result to a reverse order like this:

```
   <schools>
    <schcool>
        school5, school4, school3, school2, school1
        </schcool>
    </schools>
```

Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

DY

Comment: After you edit both XML snippets look the same. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hehe, just changed it back. thanks.

Comment: @DotNet User, not accepted any answer yet? Jut to remind.

Answer (score 4):

```
<template name="split" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <param name="s" />
  <param name="withcomma" select="false()" />
  <choose>
    <when test="contains($s, ',')">
      <!-- if there is still a comma, call me again
           with everything after the first comma... -->
      <call-template name="split">
        <with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s, ',')" />
        <with-param name="withcomma" select="true()" />
      </call-template>
      <!-- ...and print afterwards the current part -->
      <value-of select="substring-before($s, ',')" />
      <if test="$withcomma">
        <text>, </text>
      </if>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <!-- No comma left in the remaining part: print the rest -->
      <value-of select="$s" />
      <if test="$withcomma">
        <text>, </text>
      </if>
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
</template>
```

You might have to fiddle a bit with the whitespace (look up the XPath function '`normalize-space()`') to get the exact result, but the reverse sorting in principle is shown in the code above. Call it from your other templates like this:

```
  <call-template name="split">
    <with-param name="s" select="." />
  </call-template>
```

Comment: De nada. Actually, recursive calls to templates are quite frequent in XSLT. You should get used to this technique.

Comment: Beware, your function will return nothing if there aren't any commas in the text...

Comment: ...hmm. Why? The case without commata is handled by the otherwise clause, as far as I can see. It even shouldn't rpint out a superfluous trailing comma.

Comment: OK, you were half-right. There **WAS A BUG** in the old version, I just corrected it the other minute.

Comment: ...I hate the value="" and select="" attributes. I always mix them up.

Comment: Tested in Xalan: Without comma (value was "school1") the output is, as expected, precisely "school1".

Comment: I did a test, it about output the original text.

Comment: @Boldewyn, (+1) Thanks a lot. I just copied your code, splitted the string text using \r and printed each segement in new line.

Answer (score 1):

A variant without xsl:choose:

```
  <xsl:template name="reverse">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="comma" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="item" select="substring-before(concat($text, ','), ',')"/>    
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($item) != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(concat($text, ','), concat($item, ','))"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="comma" select="true()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$item"/>
    <xsl:if test="$comma and $item != ''">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Erlock, Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. You have save my time.

I remove the space by this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="split">
     <xsl:with-param name="s" select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Many thanks.

DY